# Visual Studio - cannot find DB class definition

Tags: visual-studio-2010

```
var db = DB.GetDefaultContext();
```

When I f12 DB in the above example, the class file that opens is not the one located in my Data folder. It certainly should be, but I cannot seem to manually find this class file.

Is there a "View in Finder" function in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find in files hotkey is Ctrl+Shift+F then the Result options section will allow you to tell VS2010 where to list results.